# Selenium returns element but not the text [python]

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have HTML like this:

```
<div class="bob">
    <span style="font-family:Arial; "> "John Smith " <br> "hobby : soccer " </span>
</div>
```

My code:

```
email = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "bob")
span_element = email.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "span")
```

When I `print(span_element)`, it returns:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="283d1ce4f46b65403dc3fd5f6a8bf2d9", element="9cf22600-9df7-4208-97cb-0f12afcebdd9")>
```

But if I use `print(span_element.text)`, it returns nothing, why is that? My goal is to get the content of the text.

Comment: @JohnGordon OP is using `email.find_element()` so it searches from the `email` element so it should be the only SPAN... unless there's more than one element with the class "bob".

Comment: @JeffC Oh, good point.  I missed that detail.

Answer (score 0):

Using `print(span_element)` is going to print the instance info for the `WebElement`, not the contents of that element. `print(span_element.text)` is the correct thing to use... my guess is that the contents take a second to load so you'll need to add a wait before printing the text.

NOTE: You can combine your two `.find_element()` calls into one by using a single locator, `div.bob > span`.

The updated code would look like

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
span_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.bob > span")))
print(span_element.text)
```

If that doesn't work, you'll need to wait until the element contains text

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
span_element = wait.until(lambda d: d.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.bob > span").text != "")
print(span_element.text)
```